# XCode Interface Builder Background color

Tags: xcode

I'm a newby in XCode/iOS development, and I want to change bakckground color of my label (XCode 5.0):

1. Opened my storyboard
2. Chose my label on the left side
3. Opened attributes inspector on the right side

But this tab has got settings of font, alignment, but no background color options! There is "View" section at the bottom, but it is empty. Please, tell me where can I find settings of background color? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the top select the attributes inspector. Under the section "View" there should be a spot that says "Background". click that and choose your colour.

(refer to image for help)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Select the Label click on "Attribute Inspector" and scroll down you will see background option under View Section.

Select label before you go to Attribute Inspector

Answer (score 2):

`mylabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor] ;` is the code to change the background color. You get the color name before "Color" from the names of colors in the Apple color palette.