# How to change xcode interface builder background color

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I want to change the background color of Interface Builder in Xcode, by default it is white but it messes with the other view controllers background color which is also white by default.

I don't want to change the background color of every view controllers view instead I want to change the background color of Interface Builder itself.

Comment: Is it useful for you, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206940/xcode-interface-builder-background-color

Comment: I think someone already made Xcode plugin for this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/26438240/4226970

Comment: @chinnawatp thanks for suggestion, however am bit afraid of using plugin as per my past experience. I wish there were some native setting in xcode to do so!